# Native way to perform otool -L recursively?

Tags: macos, mac

When I run `otool -L` (e.g. `otool -L /Applications/IBM/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.dylib`), I can see all the shared libraries and check that they have current version >= compatibility version

```
/Applications/IBM/informix/lib/cli/iclit09b.dylib:
    iclit09b.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    sobj4/igl4a304.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    sobj4/iglxa304.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

I can then run `otool -L` on each of those shared libraries to see if *their* shared libraries have current version >= compatibility version, and so on, recursively. But this approach is **manual**

Is there a native (i.e. `otool` or MacOS) way to return all the recursive shared libraries (and their compatibility version and current version)?

#### What I know so far

- Someone wrote a [python (2) script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517652/5783745) that does similar